# Dealing with Commander rules changes

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering

[This](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27704/do-commanders-die-if-they-go-to-the-command-zone-instead) rather old Q&A has gotten a rules change that changes the answer, so it has been updated. However, the rules change that is the basis for the update has "only" been announced by the Commander Advisory Group, while the answer implies that the rule is already active. I have no reason to doubt it will arrive as advertised, but as far as the Comprehensive Rules are concerned, it hasn't happened yet, and in sanctioned Commander events (or official online play), people would still have to play with the current rules.

Therefore I would suggest that using the CAG as a reliable preview source is fine, but the CR should still be the only source to describe the current state of Commander rules. I am open to discussion since Commander is a special case in the CR.

Comment: This makes sense to me.

Comment: I think this would have prompted more immediate and useful change if it was posted as a comment on the answer in question than as a meta question. These rules change very infrequently, so there isn't a whole lot of value in developing a general principle for handling those changes.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, CAG defines the rules for Commander - it's a format that WotC adopted after it was created and made popular by players, and I think more people follow CAG rulings than WotC rulings for the format, at least when not playing in WotC events.

Answer (score 1):

This is a couple of months ago, but I'll leave this answer just to record what happened with that post (which I'm the author of):

On June 19 I happened to see this meta, so I updated my post ([revision 7](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/27705/revisions), right at the end) to clarify the rules update was not yet present in the actual Commander rules page. I did not actually realise the rules were not already active on the Commander site's rules page until seeing this meta.

@murgatroid99 advised in comments to post a comment on my answer requesting change as well. I agree with that; I would be receptive to comments like that on my posts and would update in a situation like this, and I might not have become aware of this otherwise. I assume that such a comment didn't get posted because I happened to spot this meta pretty quickly and already acted on it.

Today I've further updated the post (revision 14) to describe the rule as present on the Commander rules page.

For those curious, I've also added Wayback machine links to my answer for before/after the rules change: [June 18](http://web.archive.org/web/20200618155207/https://mtgcommander.net/index.php/rules/), [August 18](http://web.archive.org/web/20200818085421/https://mtgcommander.net/index.php/rules/).